# Google search history based on location

Tags: api, google-search, history, google-data

I was wondering if it was possible to grab people's google search data based on a location? Wonder if there is an API available or any way to achieve this.

So for example, I would like to see what people are searching within a city, and maybe use that to predict things like mental health, etc.